# jQuery - How to input text and store the result in ASP.Net labels

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Im using jQuery to get geo coordinates in asp.net Below is the code

I want to enter the address in textbox and show the latitude and longitude in labels. Could someone suggest me right way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = "adeliade";

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            alert(latitude + ", " + longitude);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the above code works fine. But I need the address to be given from textbox and on a button click, show lat and long in labels

Comment: Well, just put a textbox and a button; and hook a function (which wraps your above code) for the button click

Comment: I have tried using that way, var address = $("#city").val();             But I dont see any message when I run the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works.

**Put the following Htmls:**

```
Address: <input type="text" id="tbCity" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Lat/Long" /> <!-- note that, this is not an asp server button control; just an html button. It should not cause a postback  --!>
```

**and these javascripts(jQuery) in the `head` tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        $("#btn").on("click", function () {
            var address = $("#tbCity").val();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    alert(latitude + ", " + longitude);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```